# 'error Command "encore" not found.' when running 'yarn run encore' in Symfony4

Tags: symfony4, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

I work in a Symfony 4.2 project, and try to use Bootstrap theming (so I need to compile Sass code). I followed the process given in the official doc, which indicates to use webpack-encore. But I have an error when using it accordingly to the doc.

Here is the page indicating the process :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html

So I installed Encore, and then I launch `yarn run encore`. And here is what it says in the terminal :

```
yarn run v1.16.0
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "encore" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

So I visited the site indicated in the error, which says :

### You may define scripts in your package.json file.

And if I look in my package.json in the root directory, it indeed only says :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

There is no script for any encore command :-(

However the rest seems good. Here is an extract of composer.json :

```
...
    "require": {
...
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.5",
...
    },
...
```

And I have a webpack.config.js .

I runned `composer require encore` and `yarn install` without any error.

But nowhere in the Symfony doc I found anything about tweaking the package.json oO So how do I make it work ? Why doesn't the `yarn run encore` work ?

Comment: Damn, I forgot a step : 'yarn init'